# How to calculate conversion rates in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Order and Advertising.

```
Order columns
1.user_id
2.order_id
3.order_sku  (e-cards, e-book)

Advertising columns 
1. user_id
2. ad_id
```

I am looking for a calculation where the denominator is all unique users who saw an ad within each order_sku . The nominator would be all unique users who purchased within each order_sku.

**The output columns shall look like this:**

```
1. order_id
2. conversion_rate for e-book (in %)
3. conversion_rate for e-cards (in %).
```

How would I do this in mySQL?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jarlh sorry, its MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

To have the conversione rates, you can use the `COUNT(*)` aggregate function with a `GROUP BY` clause.
Something like:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Order))*100 AS perc,ad_channel
FROM Order
LEFT JOIN Advertising ON Order.user_id = Advertising.user_id
GROUP BY ad_channel;
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost worked. How can I restructure the table to the following format: order_id, conversion_ad_channel1, conversion_ad_channel2 along with the '%' signs in the cells?

Comment: You can't have order id in aggregate context, because the id changes, and is not part of the aggregation. Do you expect more than 1 row in the results? If so, the how do you calculate the conversion_rate for a single order?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very strange data model.  I'm not sure how a single `order_id` would be associated with multiple users, but that seems to be what you are doing.

I think it is easier to put the different skus on different rows, so I would start with:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_sku,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.user_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id)
FROM Order o LEFT JOIN
     Advertising a
     ON o.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY o.order_id, o.order_sku;
```